# ASP.NET 4: HttpResponse open in NEW Browser?

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation, httpresponse

I am using a PDF generater that utlizes HttpResponse. Is there a way (perhaps passing a header tag) to open the PDF in a NEW windows instead of the same one? I don't want the user to be directed away from the website...

Here's the code I'm using:

```
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;        response.Clear();
response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
    "inline; filename=" + downloadName + "; size=" + downloadBytes.Length.ToString());
response.Flush();
response.BinaryWrite(downloadBytes);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

Comment: How does the user request the PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that on server side  if you have not generated the link yourself. But if you have, then as Robert said, provide a target with the `<a>` link.

There is a server-side alternative and that is to set the content type to `application/octect-stream` so that the file is download and user will be able to open it with the application of choice outside browser. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) for more.

You also need to use content disposition header to provide the file name so that client can know what file type is it **after it has been downloaded as binary**.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my.pdf;
```

Comment: "You cannot do that on server side if you have not generated the link yourself" - That's what I wanted to know. Thanks Aliostad.

Answer (score 0):

You presumably have a link on your site that directs the user to the URL where this PDF generation is done.  In that link, add `target="_blank"` to the `<a>` tag.

Comment: ... I don't mean to be a jerk but, duh? :P I'm asking whether or not it's possible from the server-side. I obviously know how to execute a `href` or javascript call.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're really asking is how to make the save dialog to show instead of having the PDF loaded into your browser, then you need to modify your header.
You are setting Content-Disposition to 'inline', change that to 'attachment'

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519

Comment: If it's attachment, then it opens a dialog. Not what I want. I want the PDF to open in the window.